# How to retain the Jquery object on each AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one script file **x.js**  which contains the below function

```
$(function(){

function aplystyles()
{
 var $table= $('table.report').dataTable(datatables_options);
// it will return dataTable Object
}

})();
```

making some ajax post in page this function again called  again it getting to access the dataTable  method of some table.

i need to maintain the **$table object** on each ajax post. how can i maintain the jquery object in ajax posts of page.

because **if same table calling the dataTable method means that time it will throws error like already initialized**. for that purpose i need to maintain that object on each ajax posts.

i tried the below way

```
  this.dataTableObj= $('table.report').dataTable(datatables_options);
```

if i added the dataTableObj to "this" means i can able to get the value of object in each ajax post.

i don't know whether it is  a correct way of maintaining the object in ajax posts in javascript.

Any help on this. what is the better way to acheive this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add some more code? Not sure what your issue is exactly.

Comment: i want to maintain $table in each ajax posts that it

Comment: where would you be accessing `this.dataTableObj` from?

Comment: You need to show how you intend to use `$table`.

Comment: @SivaRajini The answer differs based on where the Ajax call is made from. Just stub out some little code that shows where you want to use it. Is it in the same function, is it in another function, is it in the same ready block, etc. Based on that, we can help you out, right now there is not enough to know what you are doing.

Comment: @epascarello in same file and same function only.need to get pervious datatbale object thats it. did you got it ?

Comment: Than if it is the same function, you should be able to reference the same variable.

Comment: what do you meant ? i didn't get you